# Xcode 5 "the Folder already contains a git repository"

Tags: xcode, git, xcode5

Git works perfectly with Xcode 4.

When creating a new project in Xcode 4, I'm able to let Xcode create a local repository for me. No issues.

[image]

However, when using Xcode 5, This option is disabled with the error message: "the folder x already contains a git repository". It doesn’t matter which directory I try to create a project - Same error. (There are no .git folders in `.` or `..`)

[image]

Also, Xcode 5 doesn’t work with existing repos.

[image]

What should I do to fix this? Anyone else experienced problems with git and Xcode 5?

Thanks in advance.

**Xcode Version 5.0.2, Git Version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)**

Comment: Please give the version numbers for Xcode and git on your machine. I suppose you've already tried to reset both?

Comment: Added it above. I've tried reinstalling Xcode and the command line tools.

Comment: One other thing. Can you create the git folder for a project manually, using Terminal or the Github app?

Comment: git from the terminal works perfectly. Haven't used the Github app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha! Funny no one answered this question.

`Xcode->Preferences->Source Control->Enable Source Control.`

Everything works now.